# Can I pass the parameters (req, res, next) of a function to another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, parameter-passing, router

I searched a little bit but I did not find what I am searching for.
I have Node application and two functions:

```
router.get('/get/user-relevant-data', (req,res,next)=>{
    //some code is executed here
    return res.status(200).json(userRelevantData)
})
router.get('/get/updated-user', (req,res,next) => {
    // I want to call '/get/user-relevant-data' and assign the returned object to another variable
    let userRelevantData = // how to call the function here correctly?
})
```

How would I do such things (if it's feasible) or should such code be avoided? If such code should be avoided, what else could I do except putting the code of the one function into the other.

Comment: refactor out a function which loads the data, call it from both handlers.

Comment: Do you mean the following: In my Angular-Application, I have a service in which I get the updated user. So instead of trying to put the whole user together in the backend, I should call both functions from above and construct the new user in my Frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the way you set up router in that way you can apply as many middlewares as you want like this:

```
const middleware1 = require("....") //adress to the file your middleware is located
const middleware2 = require("....") //adress to the file your middleware is located


router.get('/directory', middleware1, middleware2 )
```

and in another file you define middlewares in this way :

```
exports.middleware1 = (req, res, next) => {
   //do some coding
 req.something= someDataToPass
            next()   

//you add the data you want to pass to next middleware to the req obj
// and then access that in the next middleware from the req object then
// call next to run the next middleware

}
```

then in another file or the same file you type another middleware like this:

```
exports.middleware2 = (req, res, next) => {
   //do some coding
 data = req.something
//get data from last middeleware
res.json({})
}
```

and at the same time you have access to all the req data in both middlewares

Comment: and how would I get the data from the middleware? For example the middleware returns an object how would I get and assign the object in the router.get-function? Ah, so I can just append the object to the req. So, the middleware is always called before the router. That is a nice approach which I will try!

Comment: and I forgot to tell you that you can not call next in the first middleware for example you can have an if inside the first middleware that when user is not authenticated it will not call next and you can execute res.json to return data in the first middleware. but once you call res.json you cant call it again in the next middleware